# dynamic url chaning issue with multiple files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url, dynamic-url

I have 2 files called "free.php" and "new.php".
for example consider, The free.php contains `Hi, $_GET['s']`. new.php contains `Hello, $_GET['s']`.

I get URLs like https://website.com/free/file-access from https://website.com/free?s=file-access and
https://website.com/new/john-smith from https://website.com/new?s=john-smith. that's fine.
but I have an issue with the result. https://website.com/new/john-smith loads "free.php" file code with "s=john-smith" values. I received "Hi john-smith" what I need is "Hello John-smith"

when I run free.php i want results like "Hi, file-access" ( URL be like : https://website.com/free/file-access)

when I run new.php i want results like "Hello, john-smith" (URL be like :  https://website.com/new/john-smith)

my htaccess code is

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(free)\?s=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ free.php?s=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(new)\?s=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$ new.php?s=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

.PHP removed using previous httacess code.

Please help me to solve this issue. thank you in advance.

Comment: Both of your relevant rewriterules here use the exact same pattern, so of course this is never going to reach the second one.

Comment: okay any solution to reach the second file @CBroe

Comment: Be more specific in your patterns. Not sure where `(?:[^/]*)` came from to begin with, but if you want to match `free` and `new` in those places, then write those directly.